# How to pass command line argument file in Scala?

Tags: file, scala, command-line, sbt, command-line-arguments

So far I have this in my main method:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {  

val doc: scala.xml.Elem = args(0)

}
```

However when I go to to the command and write:

```
sbt run text.xml
```

I get the following:
    [error]  found   : String
    [error]  required: scala.xml.Elem
    [error]     val doc: scala.xml.Elem = args(0)

Also, I'm not looking for a parser like scopt I just want to pass the file through to my code.

Thanks

Edit: If args(0) can't be made a scala.xml.Elem then how else will I pass the file to my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to assign String to scala.xml.Elem element. You can't just assign value with type string to scala.xml.Elem. This is what you might be looking for:

```
val doc: scala.xml.Elem = scala.xml.XML.loadFile(args(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you have a type problem. Command line args are strings, yet you assign it to doc which is of type scala.xml.Elem

Looks like you want something more like this

```
val doc = XML.loadFile(args(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

args(0) is a String, not an scala.xml.Elem object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the XML file:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {  

  val doc: scala.xml.Elem = scala.xml.XML.loadFile(args(0))

}
```